# How do I ensure that the column created by Pandas agg fn for count has a name?

Tags: python, pandas

This must be a basic question, but it is nonetheless hard to discover. Let's say I've used the the Pandas `groupby` and `agg` methods to count by some column:

```
df.groupby(['col1']).agg(['count'])
```

Then let's say I want to sort by the resulting count:

```
df.groupby(['col1']).agg(['count']).sort_values('count')
```

This gives me an error:

> KeyError: 'count'

So it seems the resulting column of counts is not in fact a column, or is a column without a key.

If this is the case, how would I sort the resulting dataframe on the count?

Comment: df.groupby(['col1']).size() or df.col1.value_counts()

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this, IMHO, both require another column name.
1) You pass on a name to the aggfunc `count` so that you can use in the sort

2) You can leave the `count` naked and use a column name directly in sorting values

Approach 1

```
df.groupby(['col1']).agg([('CountName', 'count')]).sort_values(('col2', 'CountName'))
```

Approach 2

```
df.groupby(['col1']).agg('count').sort_values('col2')
```

Comment: Consider accepting the answer if it meets your inquiry.

Comment: I updated it, check the new version and let me know how this works out for you.

Comment: iDrwish these answers still error for me. They also don't make a lot of sense right off the bat. Where is `col2` coming from? I've since found a solution that I'm not totally cotent with, but may also post that soon.

Comment: You are using `col1` as a Grouper element and then applying an aggfunc which is `count`. The `count` function actually counts entries in another column, let's call `col2` for example. Use the name of the other column in the `sort_values` operation. It would also help if you were able to provide a data sample and the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `agg` the resulting DataFrame does not use the name(s) of the function as the column name(s).

See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html

You can see the names of the columns in the resulting DataFrame by `list(df.groupby(['col1']).agg(['count']))` and then pass the desired column name - tuple - into `sort_values`

Comment: When I take the list of the result of the `agg` method call, the result is the following: `[('col1', 'count')]`. If I pass 'count' into `sort_values`, I get the key error. So this doesn't seem to provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

so close, so close...

First, let's explain why your query doesn't work, or at least doesn't work the way that you expected

```
df.groupby(['col1']).agg(['count'])
```

Hopefully your dataframe `df` has a column called `col1` because that is going to be the group name, then you want to do a count within each group. Your syntax is correct, depends on how many other columns you have, `count` function will be called on each column and your output will have as many columns as the number of columns excluding `col1`. The output column name is not just a `count`, instead, it will be a MultiIndex that you need to be prepared to work with.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,1,2,2,2]})
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1':[1,1,2,2,2], 
    'col2':[1,1,2,2,2],
    'col3':[1,1,2,2,2]
})
>>> a = df.groupby(['col1']).agg(['count'])
>>> a.index
Int64Index([1, 2], dtype='int64', name=u'col1')
>>> a.columns
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'col2', u'col3'], [u'count']], labels=[[0, 1], [0, 0]])
```

From here, if you want to sort, pass the specific MultiIndex to the sort_values function by passing a tuple and then you are good to go.

```
>>> a.sort_values(by=[('col2', 'count')])
      col2   col3
      count  count
col1    
1     2      2
2     3      3
```

The final solution should be:

```
df.groupby(['col1']).agg(['count']).sort_values([('col2', 'count')])
```